# How can I jit-compile a program that runs in a loop?

Tags: dart

I have a web listener written in dart. I want to start it quicker, thats how I found https://dart.dev/tools/dart-compile#jit-snapshot.
However, when I execute `dart compile jit-snapshot server.dart` it runs the code which will run forever and so I never get the server.jit file. When I close the web-listener after a couple seconds it works fine but thats not what i want to compile.

Dart SDK version: 2.19.0-424.0.dev (dev) (Wed Nov 23 07:45:20 2022 -0800) on "linux_arm64"

dart compile jit-snapshot server.dart

should: generate server.jit
does: run forever. When I cancel it with Ctrl+c the .jit file is not generated...

Answer (score 0):

For best performance, use AOT compilation

```
dart compile aot-snapshot server.dart
```

or build an executable

```
dart compile exe server.dart
```